# Is initialState in a mixin merged with initialState in a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Simple question : if component A declares `getInitialState` and uses mixin M that also declares `getInitialState`, will both be merged in the "final" component A ?

Use case : I have several forms which share fields and associated state, and I want to avoid code duplication between them, so that each component declares only what's specific to it. I already used mixins in the recent past, but never with state.

Comment: Try it, and see if you can render the state defined in each getInitialState.

Comment: Should try during the next hour, will report here.

Comment: Tried, answered below.

Answer (score 23):

Yes, it's possible to merge the state from component A and the state declared in mixin M used by A *if* the states don't share keys. If they share keys, the Error "Invariant Violation: mergeObjectsWithNoDuplicateKeys()" will be thrown.

PS: using React.js 0.9.0.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that propTypes is also merged.